# How to draw a cylinder with height and radius with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

How to draw a cylinder with height and radius with TikZ. According to the figure:[image]

Comment: I googled "tikz cylinder" and found this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86535 for example.

Comment: Did Manuel's comment solve your request?