# Drawing a Cylinder on a plane using tikz

Tags: tikz-graphdrawing

[image: tilted cylinder]

I would like to draw a tilted cylinder on the plane `\alpha`. Can I draw this using latex `tikz`?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! what have you done so far? Related [Drawing an intersection of two equations in 3D(with dashed lines)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238119/124842)

Comment: Another possible starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86543/36296

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,shapes.geometric,positioning,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,scale=1.5,transform shape]
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
\draw (-2,-3) rectangle (2,3);
\end{scope}
\node [cylinder,rotate=70,aspect=2,draw,
minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2cm+2*\pgflinewidth,
name path=cylinder] (cylinder) at (0.5,1,0) {};
\path[fill=white] (cylinder.195) coordinate[label=below:$A$](A) -- 
++(5:1) -- ++(-130:0.5) -- cycle;
\draw[rotate=-20,densely dashed,name path=hidden arc] ([yshift=\pgflinewidth]cylinder.before bottom) arc (0:180:1cm and 0.25cm);
\path[name path=aux2,overlay] (A) -- ++(0,6,0);
\draw[rotate=-20,densely dashed] ([yshift=\pgflinewidth]cylinder.before bottom) arc (0:-70:1cm and 0.25cm);
\draw[densely dashed] ([yshift=\pgflinewidth]cylinder.before bottom) --
++(70:0.1);
\path[name path=aux2,overlay] (A) -- ++(0,6,0);
\draw[name intersections={of=cylinder and aux2,total=\t}] (A)-- (intersection-3)
coordinate[label={above:$C$}](C);
\path (cylinder.before top) -- (cylinder.after top) coordinate[midway] (O2);
\node[fill,circle,scale=0.3,label={[right,yshift=-4pt]:$O_2$}] at (O2) {};
\path [name path=aux] (A) -- ++ (70:1);
\draw[densely dashed,name intersections={of=hidden arc and aux, by=X}] (A) -- (X) coordinate[label={[above,opacity=1]:$B$}] (B);
\node[below=1pt of cylinder.160] {$C_1$};
\node[above=1pt of cylinder.-20] {$C_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh sorry. i'm not accustomed to this yet...